# Maeklong Railway Timetable

Tags: trains, thailand

First timer heading to Bangkok and am trying to figure out timing of the Maeklong train heading towards Samut Songkhram and back, but while the railway website has an English translation, the timetable is still in PDF.

Google translate failed completely on the words and I'm struggling to figure this out.

[Here is the PDF of the timetable in Thai.](http://www.railway.co.th/home/images/content/home/srt/timetable/download/th/201110-Maeklong.pdf)

I need help with which column corresponds to which of the below four routes:

- Wongwian Yai to Mahachai
- Ban Leam to Maeklong
- Maeklong to Ban Leam
- Mahachai to Wongwian Yai

Or if that is too much to ask, what are these words saying for me to try and piece together the rest:

จากบานแหลม - แมกลอง
 จากแมกลอง - บานแหลม
 คลองนกเล็ก

Answer (score 7):

First of all, here are the names in Thai of the stations you want.  Mahachai and Ban Laem are really the same place, but you need to cross the river after arriving at Mahachai to get to Ban Laem, where the second leg begins.

> วงเวียนใหญ่ = Wongwian Yai
>
> มหาชัย = Mahachai
>
> บ้านแหลม = Ban Laem
>
> แม่กลอง = Mae Klong

The timetable you’ve posted is only for the second leg (Ban Laem to Mae Klong).  Here’s a link to the railway.co.th timetable for the first leg:

[Wongwian Yai timetable](http://www.railway.co.th/home/images/content/home/srt/timetable/WongwianYai-MahaChai.asp)

As you can see, trains leave Wongwian Yai station every hour or so starting at 5:30 AM, and it takes about an hour to get to Mahachai.  I’ve taken this train several times but never gone further than Mahachai.  It’s basically a big market and has some excellent seafood restaurants.

By the way, these trains are free for Thai citizens, but not for tourists.  It should cost around 20 baht for the first leg, as I recall.